# Is there an adapter that will let me use a Nikkor 70-210 on my D3000?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3000

Is there an adapter that will allow me to use a Nikkor 70-210 on my D3000?

Answer (score 6):

No adaptor required, but it will be manual focus only. There is no adaptor for AF drive available.